# Toggle fullscreen in Xmonad?

Tags: window-manager, xmonad, tiling-wm, fullscreen, haskell

##### I'm new around Xmonad WM and haskell is completely new to me, so be patient.

Running the almost stock ArcoLinux Xmonad.

I'm trying to setup Xmonad WM to be able to go full screen at anytime and in all apps I want, and bind that to `(modMask, xK_f)` - Basically use that binding as a toggle to go full screen in some of the apps that I need, especially the browser. while hiding the `polybar` completely.

This is my `~/.xmonad/xmonad.sh`

```
import System.IO
import System.Exit

import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers(doFullFloat, doCenterFloat, isFullscreen, isDialog)
import XMonad.Config.Desktop
import XMonad.Config.Azerty
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig (additionalKeys, additionalMouseBindings)
import XMonad.Actions.CycleWS
import XMonad.Hooks.UrgencyHook
import qualified Codec.Binary.UTF8.String as UTF8

import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
import XMonad.Layout.Gaps
import XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile
---import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
import XMonad.Layout.Fullscreen (fullscreenFull)
import XMonad.Layout.Cross(simpleCross)
import XMonad.Layout.Spiral(spiral)
import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.Instances
import XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens


import XMonad.Layout.CenteredMaster(centerMaster)

import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Control.Monad (liftM2)
import qualified DBus as D
import qualified DBus.Client as D


myStartupHook = do
    spawn "$HOME/.xmonad/scripts/autostart.sh"
    setWMName "LG3D"

-- colours
normBord = "#4c566a"
focdBord = "#5e81ac"
fore     = "#DEE3E0"
back     = "#282c34"
winType  = "#c678dd"

--mod4Mask= super key
--mod1Mask= alt key
--controlMask= ctrl key
--shiftMask= shift key

myModMask = mod4Mask
encodeCChar = map fromIntegral . B.unpack
myFocusFollowsMouse = True
myBorderWidth = 2
myWorkspaces    = ["\61612","\61899","\61947","\61635","\61502","\61501","\61705","\61564","\62150","\61872"]
--myWorkspaces    = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
--myWorkspaces    = ["I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX","X"]

myBaseConfig = desktopConfig

-- window manipulations
myManageHook = composeAll . concat $
    [ [isDialog --> doCenterFloat]
    , [className =? c --> doCenterFloat | c <- myCFloats]
    , [title =? t --> doFloat | t <- myTFloats]
    , [resource =? r --> doFloat | r <- myRFloats]
    , [resource =? i --> doIgnore | i <- myIgnores]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61612" | x <- my1Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61899" | x <- my2Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61947" | x <- my3Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61635" | x <- my4Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61502" | x <- my5Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61501" | x <- my6Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61705" | x <- my7Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61564" | x <- my8Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\62150" | x <- my9Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61872" | x <- my10Shifts]
    ]
    where
    -- doShiftAndGo = doF . liftM2 (.) W.greedyView W.shift
    myCFloats = ["Arandr", "Arcolinux-calamares-tool.py", "Arcolinux-tweak-tool.py", "Arcolinux-welcome-app.py", "Galculator", "feh", "mpv", "Xfce4-terminal"]
    myTFloats = ["Downloads", "Save As..."]
    myRFloats = []
    myIgnores = ["desktop_window"]
    -- my1Shifts = ["Chromium", "Vivaldi-stable", "Firefox"]
    -- my2Shifts = []
    -- my3Shifts = ["Inkscape"]
    -- my4Shifts = []
    -- my5Shifts = ["Gimp", "feh"]
    -- my6Shifts = ["vlc", "mpv"]
    -- my7Shifts = ["Virtualbox"]
    -- my8Shifts = ["Thunar"]
    -- my9Shifts = []
    -- my10Shifts = ["discord"]




myLayout = spacingRaw True (Border 0 5 5 5) True (Border 5 5 5 5) True $ avoidStruts $ mkToggle (NBFULL ?? NOBORDERS ?? EOT) $ tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| spiral (6/7)  ||| ThreeColMid 1 (3/100) (1/2) ||| Full
    where
        tiled = Tall nmaster delta tiled_ratio
        nmaster = 1
        delta = 3/100
        tiled_ratio = 1/2


myMouseBindings (XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $

    -- mod-button1, Set the window to floating mode and move by dragging
    [ ((modMask, 1), (\w -> focus w >> mouseMoveWindow w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button2, Raise the window to the top of the stack
    , ((modMask, 2), (\w -> focus w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button3, Set the window to floating mode and resize by dragging
    , ((modMask, 3), (\w -> focus w >> mouseResizeWindow w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    ]


-- keys config

myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- SUPER + FUNCTION KEYS

  [ ((modMask, xK_d ), spawn $ "dmenu_run -i -nb '#191919' -nf '#fea63c' -sb '#fea63c' -sf '#191919' -fn 'NotoMonoRegular:bold:pixelsize=15'")
  , ((modMask, xK_f), sendMessage $ Toggle NBFULL)
  , ((modMask, xK_Return), spawn $ "alacritty" )
  , ((modMask, xK_q), kill )
  , ((modMask, xK_t), spawn $ "termite" )
  , ((modMask, xK_r), spawn $ "rofi -show drun" )
  , ((modMask, xK_v), spawn $ "pavucontrol" )
  , ((modMask, xK_x), spawn $ "arcolinux-logout" )
  , ((modMask, xK_l), spawn $ "betterlockscreen -l" )
  , ((modMask, xK_Escape), spawn $ "xkill" )
  , ((modMask, xK_e), spawn $ "thunar" )
  , ((modMask, xK_s ), spawn $ "xfce4-settings-manager")
  --, ((modMask, xK_c), spawn $ "conky-toggle" )
  --, ((modMask, xK_y), spawn $ "polybar-msg cmd toggle" )
  

  -- FUNCTION KEYS
  , ((0, xK_F12), spawn $ "xfce4-terminal --drop-down" )

  -- SUPER + SHIFT KEYS

  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_r ), spawn $ "xmonad --recompile && xmonad --restart")
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_q ), kill)
  -- , ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_x ), io (exitWith ExitSuccess))

 
  -- CONTROL + KEYS
    

  -- CONTROL + ALT KEYS

  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_v ), spawn $ "virt-manager")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_Prior ), spawn $ "conky-rotate -p")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_a ), spawn $ "xfce4-appfinder")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_b ), spawn $ "thunar")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_c ), spawn $ "catfish")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_e ), spawn $ "arcolinux-tweak-tool")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_f ), spawn $ "firefox")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_i ), spawn $ "nitrogen")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_o ), spawn $ "$HOME/.xmonad/scripts/picom-toggle.sh")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_t ), spawn $ "urxvt")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_u ), spawn $ "pavucontrol")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_r ), spawn $ "rofi-theme-selector")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_k ), spawn $ "arcolinux-logout")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_l ), spawn $ "arcolinux-logout")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_Next ), spawn $ "conky-rotate -n")
  
  
  -- ALT + ... KEYS

  , ((mod1Mask, xK_n), spawn $ "variety -n" )
  , ((mod1Mask, xK_F3), spawn $ "xfce4-appfinder" )
  , ((mod1Mask, xK_p), spawn $ "variety -p" )
  , ((mod1Mask, xK_r), spawn $ "xmonad --restart" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_f), spawn $ "variety -f" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_t), spawn $ "variety -t" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_Up), spawn $ "variety --pause" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_Down), spawn $ "variety --resume" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_Left), spawn $ "variety -p" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_Right), spawn $ "variety -n" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_F2), spawn $ "xfce4-appfinder --collapsed" )

  --VARIETY KEYS WITH PYWAL

  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_f ), spawn $ "variety -f && wal -i $(cat $HOME/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper.jpg.txt)&")
  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_n ), spawn $ "variety -n && wal -i $(cat $HOME/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper.jpg.txt)&")
  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_p ), spawn $ "variety -p && wal -i $(cat $HOME/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper.jpg.txt)&")
  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_t ), spawn $ "variety -t && wal -i $(cat $HOME/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper.jpg.txt)&")
  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_u ), spawn $ "wal -i $(cat $HOME/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper.jpg.txt)&")

  --CONTROL + SHIFT KEYS


  --SCREENSHOTS

  , ((0, xK_Print), spawn $ "flameshot gui")
  --, ((0, xK_Print), spawn $ "scrot 'ArcoLinux-%Y-%m-%d-%s_screenshot_$wx$h.jpg' -e 'mv $f $$(xdg-user-dir PICTURES)'")
  , ((controlMask, xK_Print), spawn $ "xfce4-screenshooter" )
  , ((controlMask .|. shiftMask , xK_Print ), spawn $ "gnome-screenshot -a -c")


  --MULTIMEDIA KEYS

  -- Mute volume
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioMute), spawn $ "amixer -q set Master toggle")

  -- Decrease volume
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioLowerVolume), spawn $ "amixer -q set Master 5%-")

  -- Increase volume
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume), spawn $ "amixer -q set Master 5%+")

  -- Increase brightness
  , ((0, xF86XK_MonBrightnessUp),  spawn $ "light -A 5")

  -- Decrease brightness
  , ((0, xF86XK_MonBrightnessDown), spawn $ "light -U 5")

--  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioPlay), spawn $ "mpc toggle")
--  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioNext), spawn $ "mpc next")
--  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioPrev), spawn $ "mpc prev")
--  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioStop), spawn $ "mpc stop")

  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioPlay), spawn $ "playerctl play-pause")
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioNext), spawn $ "playerctl next")
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioPrev), spawn $ "playerctl previous")
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioStop), spawn $ "playerctl stop")


  --------------------------------------------------------------------
  --  XMONAD LAYOUT KEYS

  -- Cycle through the available layout algorithms.
  , ((modMask, xK_space), sendMessage NextLayout)

  --Focus selected desktop
  , ((mod1Mask, xK_Tab), nextWS)

  --Focus selected desktop
  , ((modMask, xK_Tab), nextWS)

  --Focus selected desktop
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_Left ), prevWS)

  --Focus selected desktop
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_Right ), nextWS)

  --  Reset the layouts on the current workspace to default.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_space), setLayout $ XMonad.layoutHook conf)

  -- Move focus to the next window.
  , ((modMask, xK_j), windows W.focusDown)

  -- Move focus to the previous window.
  , ((modMask, xK_k), windows W.focusUp  )

  -- Move focus to the master window.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_m), windows W.focusMaster  )

  -- Swap the focused window with the next window.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_j), windows W.swapDown  )

  -- Swap the focused window with the next window.
  , ((controlMask .|. modMask, xK_Down), windows W.swapDown  )

  -- Swap the focused window with the previous window.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_k), windows W.swapUp    )

  -- Swap the focused window with the previous window.
  , ((controlMask .|. modMask, xK_Up), windows W.swapUp  )

  -- Shrink the master area.
  , ((controlMask .|. shiftMask , xK_h), sendMessage Shrink)

  -- Expand the master area.
  , ((controlMask .|. shiftMask , xK_l), sendMessage Expand)

  -- Push window back into tiling.
  , ((controlMask .|. shiftMask , xK_t), withFocused $ windows . W.sink)

  -- Increment the number of windows in the master area.
  , ((controlMask .|. modMask, xK_Left), sendMessage (IncMasterN 1))

  -- Decrement the number of windows in the master area.
  , ((controlMask .|. modMask, xK_Right), sendMessage (IncMasterN (-1)))

  ]
  ++

  -- mod-[1..9], Switch to workspace N
  -- mod-shift-[1..9], Move client to workspace N
  [((m .|. modMask, k), windows $ f i)

  --Keyboard layouts
  --qwerty users use this line
   | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_1,xK_2,xK_3,xK_4,xK_5,xK_6,xK_7,xK_8,xK_9,xK_0]

  --French Azerty users use this line
  -- | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_ampersand, xK_eacute, xK_quotedbl, xK_apostrophe, xK_parenleft, xK_minus, xK_egrave, xK_underscore, xK_ccedilla , xK_agrave]

  --Belgian Azerty users use this line
  -- | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_ampersand, xK_eacute, xK_quotedbl, xK_apostrophe, xK_parenleft, xK_section, xK_egrave, xK_exclam, xK_ccedilla, xK_agrave]

      , (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)
      , (\i -> W.greedyView i . W.shift i, shiftMask)]]

  ++
  -- ctrl-{w,e,r}, Switch to physical/Xinerama screens 1, 2, or 3
  -- ctrl-shift-{w,e,r}, Move client to screen 1, 2, or 3
  [((m .|. controlMask, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (windows . f))
      | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_w, xK_e] [0..]
      , (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]


main :: IO ()
main = do

    dbus <- D.connectSession
    -- Request access to the DBus name
    D.requestName dbus (D.busName_ "org.xmonad.Log")
        [D.nameAllowReplacement, D.nameReplaceExisting, D.nameDoNotQueue]


    xmonad . ewmh $
  --Keyboard layouts
  --qwerty users use this line
            myBaseConfig
  --French Azerty users use this line
            --myBaseConfig { keys = azertyKeys <+> keys azertyConfig }
  --Belgian Azerty users use this line
            --myBaseConfig { keys = belgianKeys <+> keys belgianConfig }

                {startupHook = myStartupHook
, layoutHook = gaps [(U,35), (D,5), (R,5), (L,5)] $ myLayout ||| layoutHook myBaseConfig
, manageHook = manageSpawn <+> myManageHook <+> manageHook myBaseConfig
, modMask = myModMask
, borderWidth = myBorderWidth
, handleEventHook    = handleEventHook myBaseConfig <+> fullscreenEventHook
, focusFollowsMouse = myFocusFollowsMouse
, workspaces = myWorkspaces
, focusedBorderColor = focdBord
, normalBorderColor = normBord
, keys = myKeys
, mouseBindings = myMouseBindings
}
```

Comment: My other answer [from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697441/how-to-remove-borders-from-all-full-screen-floating-windows-in-xmonad) actually explains how to do exactly this and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a way to do that all in one keybinding but it can be done in two.

Remove avoidStruts from your myLayout so it looks like it does below:

```
myLayout = spacingRaw True (Border 0 5 5 5) True (Border 5 5 5 5) True $ mkToggle (NBFULL ?? NOBORDERS ?? EOT) $ tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| spiral (6/7)  ||| ThreeColMid 1 (3/100) (1/2) ||| Full
where
    tiled = Tall nmaster delta tiled_ratio
    nmaster = 1
    delta = 3/100
    tiled_ratio = 1/2
```

Add the following to the "SUPER + FUNCTION KEYS":

```
  , ((modMask, xK_b), sendMessage ToggleGaps >> spawn "polybar-msg cmd toggle")
```

Once those changes are made, you can do SUPER + F and then SUPER + B to get an app to be fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this solution ASAP.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: Yes, it does work, thanks very much :) I just don't like that when I go full screen on monitor one, it takes down `polybar` from all monitors, could I change to only toggle `polybar` on that specific monitor? And `alacritty` doesn't go full screen, although termite and urxvt go full screen :/
I see that you've just removed `avoidStruts`? What did that do?

Comment: You had the gaps that made a space for the polybar but also the avoidstruts which does the same thing twice so removing avoidstruts made it so that you could toggle gaps instead of toggling both.

Comment: ,((modMask, xK_b), sendMessage $ ToggleGaps)

Comment: That will just toggle the gaps and not the polybar which will work on most applications but for terminals with transparency the polybar will still be there in the background

Comment: That line should replace the one I gave you before and you should uncomment the line with “polybar-msg cmd toggle”. I don’t know why alacritty is not fullscreening for you since it works for me. What do you see when it doesn’t work?

Comment: To get rid of the polybar behind a transparent window, you can do Super+y to toggle the polybar once you have uncommented it.

Answer (score 0):

This also works to launch an app in full screen:

```
, ((modMask, xK_x), sendMessage  (JumpToLayout "Full")  >> spawn "archlinux-logout")
```

To just jump to full screen mode, do:

```
, ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_l), sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "Full"  )
```