# How to remove borders from all full screen floating windows in XMonad

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, xmonad

I've been trying to achieve this for some time now. But can't figure it out how can I do this.
On this topic I've found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bauXm__slAM) that explains very well exactly what I want to achieve but I can't wrap my head around it cause my config file it's been written way different than [the one he has in the video](https://github.com/NapoleonWils0n/ubuntu-dotfiles/blob/master/.config/xmonad/xmonad.hs).
One thing. I have a two monitor setup.

##### Can anyone help with this? Any explanation or help is highly appreciated.

### Here's the relevant part from my `xmonad.hs` config file

```
import System.IO
import System.Exit

import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers(doFullFloat, doCenterFloat, isFullscreen, isDialog)
import XMonad.Config.Desktop
import XMonad.Config.Azerty
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig (additionalKeys, additionalMouseBindings)
import XMonad.Actions.CycleWS
import XMonad.Hooks.UrgencyHook
import qualified Codec.Binary.UTF8.String as UTF8

import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
import XMonad.Layout.Gaps
import XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
import XMonad.Layout.Fullscreen (fullscreenFull)
import XMonad.Layout.Cross(simpleCross)
import XMonad.Layout.Spiral(spiral)
import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.Instances
import XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens


import XMonad.Layout.CenteredMaster(centerMaster)

import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Control.Monad (liftM2)
import qualified DBus as D
import qualified DBus.Client as D


myStartupHook = do
    spawn "$HOME/.xmonad/scripts/autostart.sh"
    setWMName "LG3D"

-- colours
normBord = "#4c566a"
focdBord = "#5e81ac"
fore     = "#DEE3E0"
back     = "#282c34"
winType  = "#c678dd"

--mod4Mask= super key
--mod1Mask= alt key
--controlMask= ctrl key
--shiftMask= shift key

myModMask = mod4Mask
encodeCChar = map fromIntegral . B.unpack
myFocusFollowsMouse = True
myBorderWidth = 2
myWorkspaces    = ["\61612","\61899","\61947","\61635","\61502","\61501","\61705","\61564","\62150","\61872"]
--myWorkspaces    = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
--myWorkspaces    = ["I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX","X"]

myBaseConfig = desktopConfig

-- window manipulations
myManageHook = composeAll . concat $
    [ [isDialog --> doCenterFloat]
    , [className =? c --> doCenterFloat | c <- myCFloats]
    , [title =? t --> doFloat | t <- myTFloats]
    , [resource =? r --> doFloat | r <- myRFloats]
    , [resource =? i --> doIgnore | i <- myIgnores]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61612" | x <- my1Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61899" | x <- my2Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61947" | x <- my3Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61635" | x <- my4Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61502" | x <- my5Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61501" | x <- my6Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61705" | x <- my7Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61564" | x <- my8Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\62150" | x <- my9Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61872" | x <- my10Shifts]
    ]
    where
    -- doShiftAndGo = doF . liftM2 (.) W.greedyView W.shift
    myCFloats = ["Arandr", "Arcolinux-calamares-tool.py", "Arcolinux-tweak-tool.py", "Arcolinux-welcome-app.py", "Galculator", "feh", "Xfce4-terminal"]
    myTFloats = ["Downloads", "Save As..."]
    myRFloats = []
    myIgnores = ["desktop_window"]
    -- my1Shifts = ["Chromium", "Vivaldi-stable", "Firefox"]
    -- my2Shifts = []
    -- my3Shifts = ["Inkscape"]
    -- my4Shifts = []
    -- my5Shifts = ["Gimp", "feh"]
    -- my6Shifts = ["vlc", "mpv"]
    -- my7Shifts = ["Virtualbox"]
    -- my8Shifts = ["Thunar"]
    -- my9Shifts = []
    -- my10Shifts = ["discord"]




myLayout = spacingRaw True (Border 0 5 5 5) True (Border 5 5 5 5) True $ mkToggle (NBFULL ?? NOBORDERS ?? EOT) $ tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| spiral (6/7)  ||| ThreeColMid 1 (3/100) (1/2) ||| noBorders Full
    where
        tiled = Tall nmaster delta tiled_ratio
        nmaster = 1
        delta = 3/100
        tiled_ratio = 1/2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution on this. I went an studied my `xmonad.hs` thoroughly and started understanding how things work and what should I replace in order to make it work well the way I want it to.
So I've merged my old config file (which had the keybindings that I wanted and got used to), [with this one which had the layouts that I wanted](https://github.com/NapoleonWils0n/ubuntu-dotfiles/blob/e2c668be02eb1202712c8ba12989bcf267ddbfe4/.config/xmonad/xmonad.hs).
If you want to go deeper into this, maybe [DTs configs](https://gitlab.com/dwt1/dotfiles) would help since there's a lot of stuff there also.

#### Anyways, here's how I made it work for me:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- import
------------------------------------------------------------------------

import XMonad hiding ( (|||) ) -- jump to layout
import XMonad.Config.Desktop
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import System.Exit
import System.IO

-- data
import Data.Char (isSpace)
import Data.List
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Maybe (isJust)
import Data.Ratio ((%)) -- for video
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Control.Monad (liftM2)
import qualified DBus as D
import qualified DBus.Client as D

-- util
import XMonad.Util.Run (safeSpawn, unsafeSpawn, runInTerm, spawnPipe)
import XMonad.Util.SpawnOnce
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig (additionalKeysP, additionalMouseBindings)  
import XMonad.Util.NamedScratchpad
import XMonad.Util.NamedWindows
import XMonad.Util.WorkspaceCompare

-- hooks
--import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks (avoidStruts, docksStartupHook, manageDocks, ToggleStruts(..))
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops -- to show workspaces in application switchers
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers (isFullscreen, isDialog,  doFullFloat, doCenterFloat, doRectFloat) 
import XMonad.Hooks.Place (placeHook, withGaps, smart)
import XMonad.Hooks.UrgencyHook
import qualified Codec.Binary.UTF8.String as UTF8

-- actions
import XMonad.Actions.UpdatePointer -- update mouse postion
import XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn
import XMonad.Actions.CycleWS


-- layout 
import XMonad.Layout.LayoutCombinators (JumpToLayout(..), (|||)) -- jump to layout
import XMonad.Layout.Renamed (renamed, Rename(Replace))
-- import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
import qualified XMonad.Layout.NoBorders as BO
import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
import XMonad.Layout.GridVariants
import XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile
import XMonad.Layout.BinarySpacePartition
import XMonad.Layout.Fullscreen (fullscreenFull)
import XMonad.Layout.Cross(simpleCross)
import XMonad.Layout.Spiral(spiral)
import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.Instances
import XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens
import XMonad.Layout.CenteredMaster(centerMaster)


------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- variables
------------------------------------------------------------------------

myModMask = mod4Mask -- Sets modkey to super/windows key
myTerminal = "alacritty" -- Sets default terminal
myBorderWidth = 2 -- Sets border width for windows
encodeCChar = map fromIntegral . B.unpack
myFocusFollowsMouse = True
--myNormalBorderColor = "#839496"
--myFocusedBorderColor = "#268BD2"
myWorkspaces    = ["\61612","\61899","\61947","\61635","\61502","\61501","\61705","\61564","\62150","\61872"]
--myWorkspaces    = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
--myWorkspaces    = ["I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX","X"]


------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- desktop notifications -- dunst package required
------------------------------------------------------------------------

data LibNotifyUrgencyHook = LibNotifyUrgencyHook deriving (Read, Show)

instance UrgencyHook LibNotifyUrgencyHook where
    urgencyHook LibNotifyUrgencyHook w = do
        name     <- getName w
        Just idx <- fmap (W.findTag w) $ gets windowset

        safeSpawn "notify-send" [show name, "workspace " ++ idx]

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Startup hook
------------------------------------------------------------------------

myStartupHook = do
      spawn "$HOME/.xmonad/scripts/autostart.sh"
      setWMName "LG3D"

-- colours
normBord = "#4c566a"
focdBord = "#5e81ac"
fore     = "#DEE3E0"
back     = "#282c34"
winType  = "#c678dd"

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- layout
------------------------------------------------------------------------

myLayout = BO.lessBorders BO.Never $ avoidStruts (full ||| tiled ||| grid ||| bsp)
  where
    
      -- full
     full = renamed [Replace "Full"] 
          $ BO.noBorders (Full)
      
      --- tiled
     tiled = renamed [Replace "Tall"] 
           $ spacingRaw True (Border 10 0 10 0) True (Border 0 10 0 10) True
           -- $ spacingRaw True (Border 0 5 5 5) True (Border 5 5 5 5) True 
           $ ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2) []
      -- grid
    
     grid = renamed [Replace "Grid"] 
          $ spacingRaw True (Border 10 0 10 0) True (Border 0 10 0 10) True 
          $ Grid (16/10)
    
     -- bsp
     bsp = renamed [Replace "BSP"] 
         $ emptyBSP

     -- The default number of windows in the master pane
     nmaster = 1
     
     -- Default proportion of screen occupied by master pane
     ratio   = 1/2

     -- Percent of screen to increment by when resizing panes
     delta   = 3/100

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Window rules:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
myManageHook = composeAll
    [ isDialog                      --> doCenterFloat
    , isFullscreen                  --> doFullFloat
    , className =? "mpv"            --> doRectFloat (W.RationalRect (1 % 4) (1 % 4) (1 % 2) (1 % 2))
    , title =?  "virt-manager"      --> doFloat
    , className =? "Gimp"           --> doFloat 
    --, className =? "Brave"          --> doFloat
    , className =? "Firefox" <&&> resource =? "Toolkit" --> doFloat -- firefox pip
    --, title =? "emacs-capture"      --> doRectFloat (W.RationalRect (1 % 4) (1 % 4) (1 % 2) (1 % 2)) -- emacs org capture
    , title =?  "Downloads"         --> doCenterFloat
    , title =?  "Save As..."        --> doCenterFloat
    , title =?  "Arandr"                        --> doCenterFloat
    , title =?  "Arcolinux-calamares-tool.py"   --> doCenterFloat
    , title =?  "Arcolinux-tweak-tool.py"       --> doCenterFloat
    , title =?  "Arcolinux-welcome-app.py"      --> doCenterFloat
    , title =?  "galculator"                    --> doCenterFloat
    , title =?  "feh"                           --> doCenterFloat
    , title =?  "Xfce4-terminal"                --> doCenterFloat
    --, title =?  ""                  --> doCenterFloat
    --, title =?  ""                  --> doCenterFloat
    , resource  =? "desktop_window" --> doIgnore
    , resource  =? "kdesktop"       --> doIgnore 
    ]
    
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Key bindings. Add, modify or remove key bindings here.
------------------------------------------------------------------------

myMouseBindings (XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $

    -- mod-button1, Set the window to floating mode and move by dragging
    [ ((modMask, 1), (\w -> focus w >> mouseMoveWindow w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button2, Raise the window to the top of the stack
    , ((modMask, 2), (\w -> focus w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button3, Set the window to floating mode and resize by dragging
    , ((modMask, 3), (\w -> focus w >> mouseResizeWindow w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    ]
--
--myKeys =
--  [("M-" ++ m ++ k, windows $ f i)
--        | (i, k) <- zip (myWorkspaces) (map show [1 :: Int ..])
--        , (f, m) <- [(W.view, ""), (W.shift, "S-"), (copy, "S-C-")]]
--    ++
--    [("S-C-a", windows copyToAll)   -- copy window to all workspaces
--     , ("S-C-z", killAllOtherCopies)  -- kill copies of window on other workspaces
--     , ("M-a", sendMessage MirrorExpand)
--     , ("M-z", sendMessage MirrorShrink)
--     , ("M-s", sendMessage ToggleStruts)
--     , ("M-f", sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "Full")
--     , ("M-t", sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "Tall")
--     , ("M-g", sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "Grid")
--     , ("M-b", sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "BSP")
--     , ("M-p", spawn "rofi -show drun") -- rofi
--     , ("S-M-t", withFocused $ windows . W.sink) -- flatten floating window to tiled
--     , ("M-C-<Space>", namedScratchpadAction myScratchpads "terminal")
--     , ("M-C-<Return>", namedScratchpadAction myScratchpads "emacs-scratch")
--    ]

myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- SUPER + FUNCTION KEYS

  [ ((modMask, xK_d ), spawn $ "dmenu_run -i -nb '#191919' -nf '#fea63c' -sb '#fea63c' -sf '#191919' -fn 'NotoMonoRegular:bold:pixelsize=15'")
  --, ((modMask, xK_f), sendMessage ToggleGaps >> spawn "polybar-msg cmd toggle" )
  --, ((modMask, xK_b), sendMessage $ Toggle NBFULL)
  , ((modMask, xK_a), sendMessage MirrorExpand )
  , ((modMask, xK_z), sendMessage MirrorShrink )
  , ((modMask, xK_s), sendMessage ToggleStruts )
  , ((modMask, xK_f), sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "Full" )
  , ((modMask, xK_t), sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "Tall" ) 
  , ((modMask, xK_g), sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "Grid" ) 
  , ((modMask, xK_b), sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "BSP" ) 
  , ((modMask, xK_Return), spawn $ "alacritty" )
  , ((modMask, xK_q), kill )
  , ((modMask, xK_space), spawn $ "rofi -show drun" )
  , ((modMask, xK_x), spawn $ "arcolinux-logout" )
  , ((modMask, xK_Escape), spawn $ "xkill" )
  , ((modMask, xK_e), spawn $ "" )
  , ((modMask, xK_y), spawn $ "polybar-msg cmd toggle" )
  --, ((modMask, xK_s ), spawn $ "")
  --, ((modMask, xK_v), spawn $ "" )
  --, ((modMask, xK_c), spawn $ "conky-toggle" )
  

  -- FUNCTION KEYS
  , ((0, xK_F12), spawn $ "xfce4-terminal --drop-down" )

  -- SUPER + SHIFT KEYS

  
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_r ), spawn $ "xmonad --recompile && xmonad --restart")
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_q ), kill)
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_Return ), spawn $ "termite")
  --, ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_h ), spawn $ "betterlockscreen -l && arcolinux-logout && xdotool key h"   )
  -- , ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_x ), io (exitWith ExitSuccess))

 
  -- CONTROL + KEYS
    

  -- CONTROL + ALT KEYS
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_l), spawn $ "betterlockscreen -l")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_v ), spawn $ "virt-manager")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_Prior ), spawn $ "conky-rotate -p")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_a ), spawn $ "xfce4-appfinder")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_b ), spawn $ "brave")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_e ), spawn $ "thunar")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_w ), spawn $ "waterfox-g4")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_ ), spawn $ "")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_f ), spawn $ "firefox")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_t ), spawn $ "telegram-desktop")
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_s ), spawn $ "signal-desktop")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_v ), spawn $ "pavucontrol")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_t ), spawn $ "xfce4-terminal")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_i ), spawn $ "nitrogen")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_r ), spawn $ "rofi-theme-selector")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_o ), spawn $ "$HOME/.xmonad/scripts/picom-toggle.sh")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_c ), spawn $ "catfish")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_k ), spawn $ "arcolinux-logout")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_l ), spawn $ "arcolinux-logout")
  --, ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_Next ), spawn $ "conky-rotate -n")
  
  
  -- ALT + ... KEYS

  , ((mod1Mask, xK_n), spawn $ "variety -n" )
  , ((mod1Mask, xK_F3), spawn $ "xfce4-appfinder" )
  , ((mod1Mask, xK_p), spawn $ "variety -p" )
  , ((mod1Mask, xK_r), spawn $ "xmonad --restart" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_f), spawn $ "variety -f" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_t), spawn $ "variety -t" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_Up), spawn $ "variety --pause" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_Down), spawn $ "variety --resume" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_Left), spawn $ "variety -p" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_Right), spawn $ "variety -n" )
  --, ((mod1Mask, xK_F2), spawn $ "xfce4-appfinder --collapsed" )

  --VARIETY KEYS WITH PYWAL

  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_f ), spawn $ "variety -f && wal -i $(cat $HOME/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper.jpg.txt)&")
  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_n ), spawn $ "variety -n && wal -i $(cat $HOME/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper.jpg.txt)&")
  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_p ), spawn $ "variety -p && wal -i $(cat $HOME/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper.jpg.txt)&")
  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_t ), spawn $ "variety -t && wal -i $(cat $HOME/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper.jpg.txt)&")
  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_u ), spawn $ "wal -i $(cat $HOME/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper.jpg.txt)&")

  --CONTROL + SHIFT KEYS
  --, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask , xK_Return ), spawn $ ""
  

  --SCREENSHOTS

  , ((0, xK_Print), spawn $ "flameshot gui")
  --, ((0, xK_Print), spawn $ "scrot 'ArcoLinux-%Y-%m-%d-%s_screenshot_$wx$h.jpg' -e 'mv $f $$(xdg-user-dir PICTURES)'")
  , ((controlMask, xK_Print), spawn $ "xfce4-screenshooter" )
  , ((controlMask .|. shiftMask , xK_Print ), spawn $ "xfce4-screenshooter -r -c")


  --MULTIMEDIA KEYS

  -- Mute volume
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioMute), spawn $ "amixer -q set Master toggle")

  -- Decrease volume
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioLowerVolume), spawn $ "amixer -q set Master 5%-")

  -- Increase volume
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume), spawn $ "amixer -q set Master 5%+")

  -- Increase brightness
  , ((0, xF86XK_MonBrightnessUp),  spawn $ "light -A 5")

  -- Decrease brightness
  , ((0, xF86XK_MonBrightnessDown), spawn $ "light -U 5")

--  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioPlay), spawn $ "mpc toggle")
--  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioNext), spawn $ "mpc next")
--  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioPrev), spawn $ "mpc prev")
--  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioStop), spawn $ "mpc stop")

  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioPlay), spawn $ "playerctl play-pause")
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioNext), spawn $ "playerctl next")
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioPrev), spawn $ "playerctl previous")
  , ((0, xF86XK_AudioStop), spawn $ "playerctl stop")


  --------------------------------------------------------------------
  --  XMONAD LAYOUT KEYS

  -- Cycle through the available layout algorithms.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_l), sendMessage NextLayout )

  --Focus selected desktop
  , ((mod1Mask, xK_Tab), windows W.focusDown)

  --Focus selected desktop
  , ((modMask, xK_Tab), nextWS)

  --Focus selected desktop
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_Left ), prevWS)

  --Focus selected desktop
  , ((controlMask .|. mod1Mask , xK_Right ), nextWS)

  --  Reset the layouts on the current workspace to default.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_space), setLayout $ XMonad.layoutHook conf)

  -- Move focus to the next window.
  , ((modMask, xK_j), windows W.focusDown)

  -- Move focus to the previous window.
  , ((modMask, xK_k), windows W.focusUp  )

  -- Move focus to the master window.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_m), windows W.focusMaster  )

  -- Swap the focused window with the next window.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_j), windows W.swapDown  )

  -- Swap the focused window with the next window.
  , ((controlMask .|. modMask, xK_Down), windows W.swapDown  )

  -- Swap the focused window with the previous window.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_k), windows W.swapUp    )

  -- Swap the focused window with the previous window.
  , ((controlMask .|. modMask, xK_Up), windows W.swapUp  )

  -- Shrink the master area.
  , ((controlMask .|. shiftMask , xK_h), sendMessage Shrink)

  -- Expand the master area.
  , ((controlMask .|. shiftMask , xK_l), sendMessage Expand)

  -- Push window back into tiling.
  , ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_t), withFocused $ windows . W.sink)

  -- Increment the number of windows in the master area.
  , ((controlMask .|. modMask, xK_Left), sendMessage (IncMasterN 1))

  -- Decrement the number of windows in the master area.
  , ((controlMask .|. modMask, xK_Right), sendMessage (IncMasterN (-1)))

  ]
  ++

  -- mod-[1..9], Switch to workspace N
  -- mod-shift-[1..9], Move client to workspace N
  [((m .|. modMask, k), windows $ f i)

  --Keyboard layouts
  --qwerty users use this line
   | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_1,xK_2,xK_3,xK_4,xK_5,xK_6,xK_7,xK_8,xK_9,xK_0]

       , (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)
      , (\i -> W.greedyView i . W.shift i, shiftMask)]]

  -- ++
  -- ctrl-{w,e,r}, Switch to physical/Xinerama screens 1, 2, or 3
  -- ctrl-shift-{w,e,r}, Move client to screen 1, 2, or 3
  --[((m .|. controlMask, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (windows . f))
  --    | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_w, xK_e] [0..]
  --    , (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]


------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- scratchpads
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--myScratchpads = [ NS "terminal" spawnTerm findTerm manageTerm
--              , NS "emacs-scratch" spawnEmacsScratch findEmacsScratch manageEmacsScratch
--                ] 
--    where
--    role = stringProperty "WM_WINDOW_ROLE"
--    spawnTerm = myTerminal ++  " -name scratchpad"
--    findTerm = resource =? "scratchpad"
--    manageTerm = nonFloating
--    findEmacsScratch = title =? "emacs-scratch"
--    spawnEmacsScratch = "emacsclient -a='' -nc --frame-parameters='(quote (font . \"Inconsolata:size=24:weight=regular:antialias=true:hinting=true:hintstyle=hintfull\")(name . \"emacs-scratch\"))'"
--    manageEmacsScratch = nonFloating
    
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- main
------------------------------------------------------------------------
main :: IO ()
main = do
    dbus <- D.connectSession
    -- Request access to the DBus name
    D.requestName dbus (D.busName_ "org.xmonad.Log")
        [D.nameAllowReplacement, D.nameReplaceExisting, D.nameDoNotQueue]

    
    
    xmonad $ withUrgencyHook LibNotifyUrgencyHook $ ewmh desktopConfig
        { manageHook = ( isFullscreen --> doFullFloat ) <+> manageDocks <+> myManageHook <+> manageHook desktopConfig
        , startupHook        = myStartupHook
        , layoutHook         = myLayout
        , handleEventHook    = handleEventHook desktopConfig
        , workspaces         = myWorkspaces
        , borderWidth        = myBorderWidth
        , terminal           = myTerminal
        , modMask            = myModMask
        , normalBorderColor  = normBord
        , focusedBorderColor = focdBord
        , logHook            = updatePointer (0.25, 0.25) (0.25, 0.25)
        , keys = myKeys
        , mouseBindings = myMouseBindings
        }
```